# Obtaining the size of a Clob object

Tags: c++, occi

I am trying to call a stored procedure from C++ code using OCCI.
The stored procedure has the following signature:

create or replace PROCEDURE "MYTESTPROC" (
   param1     OUT NUMBER,
   param2     OUT int,
   param3     OUT smallint,
   param4     OUT int,
   param5     OUT RAW,
   param6     OUT int,
   param7     IN OUT CLOB
)

The code which I'm using is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <occi.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace oracle::occi;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string user="test";
    std::string pass="test";
    std::string db="//192.168.1.5/Test";
    int len;

    Environment *env = Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::DEFAULT);
    Connection *con = env->createConnection(user, pass, db);
    Statement *stmt = con->createStatement("BEGIN MYTESTPROC(:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7); END;");

    stmt->registerOutParam(1, OCCINUMBER);
    stmt->registerOutParam(2, OCCIINT);
    stmt->registerOutParam(3, OCCINUMBER);
    stmt->registerOutParam(4, OCIINT);
    stmt->registerOutParam(5, OCCIBYTES);
    stmt->registerOutParam(6, OCCIINT);
    stmt->registerOutParam(7, OCCICLOB);

   ResultSet *rs = stmt->executeQuery();
   Clob clob2 = stmt->getClob(7);

   len = clob2.length();
   printf("len=%d\n", len);

   Stream *in = clob2.getStream(1, 0);

   con->terminateStatement(stmt);
   env->terminateConnection(con);
   Environment::terminateEnvironment(env);

   return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the length of the clob (len) is set to 0.
The pointer to the stream object is not NULL and the clob is initialized and open.

Please advise if I am doing something wrong.

Thanks!